# SUMIF or IF when sum is more than zero

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

In Google Sheets, I would like to get - at the bottom-most cell of a column - the sum of each cell (except for row 1, the header) above in that column ONLY if the total is greater than zero, (I don't want to see 0's when the column is blank). Can I do that with a `SUMIF` function, (if yes, how?) or, I need to use an `IF` function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

paste into any cell of A column:

```
=IF(SUM(INDIRECT("A2:A"&ROW()-1))>0, SUM(INDIRECT("A2:A"&ROW()-1)), )
```

Comment: The problem with that is that it's not dynamic, if I drag this formula to the right of this cell, it doesn't change, i.e. A2:A stays the same in all columns, as opposed to becoming B2:B, C2:C, etc. How do I make it "column dynamic"?

Comment: in that case use: `=IF(SUM(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(2, COLUMN(), 4)&":"&ADDRESS(ROW()-1, COLUMN(), 4)))>0, SUM(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(2, COLUMN(), 4)&":"&ADDRESS(ROW()-1, COLUMN(), 4))), )`

Comment: You are awesome!

Comment: Now, how do I get at the bottom-most cell of a column the sum of each cell of that column, except if the A cell of that row = "Fish" (and except for row 1, the header)? This needs to be relative, as I would like to drag the formula to the right for all columns.

Comment: can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JbledqgP-42hbGGghP9o3S8chOvNHEOMzOVoqShm3Y8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @Bilha https://i.stack.imgur.com/UCnmO.png